# Preserving a set of values throughout app

Tags: android

I just began Android Development today, so bear with me if I'm missing something.

In my MainActivity I've text fields for IP and Port, and a button to take me to `Activity2` using an Intent which passes these values.

Now in `Activity2` I create a socket connection, and I have a 4 buttons which take me to 4 different Activities `Activity2a`,`Activity2b`,`Activity2c`,`Activity2d`.

Now in these Activities, I need those IP and Port values which I entered in `MainActivity` and the `socket` I created in `Activity2`.

How can I access those? Okay I can forward those IP and Port values from `Activity2` to `Activity2b`, but that seems a bit hacky. Is there a way to create values that can be accessed throughout?

Also, what about the `socket` variable? How can I use it in `Activity2b`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not inherit all your activities from a BaseActivity and this activity inherits from Activity.

BaseActivity can hold static values which can be accessed in other activities. 
Or you can have these values in your custom `Application` class. Application class can be accessed throughout your application.

The other option is to use `SharedPreferences` to hold these integers.

Comment: Using static variables to pass state around in Application or Activity classes is very un-Android and will likely cause headaches later on. For example, the user switches away from ActivityB after it has assumed that state is held in a static variable in ActivityA. After opening five more apps, Android has cleared your app's memory (and static variables), but the user switches back to your app in the recent task launcher. ActivityB is re-created and crashes because the static variable in ActivityA is null.

Comment: Additonally, because so many objects in Android have a Context, holding onto these things statically will leak all sorts of memory.

Comment: We are taking of having static variables in Application class and not activity class. From your example, even if Activity A is removed by the framework, the application class variables will still retain the previous values. If the application is removed by the framework, it means next time when the user launches, its launcher activity is invoked (MainActivity in this case) so that the user types in the port no and ip address again. Having static variables might not be the perfect solution, but it can be a one if there arent any better ones.

Comment: There are better solutions.

Comment: Storing primitive types in application won't cause memory leaks! How can it?

Comment: Application won't leak context, but getting into the habit of keeping all of these statics around at the Activity level can. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: @JonWillis Sorry, didn't notice that this also suggests storing statics in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just save all the values you want in `SharedPreferences`

Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
Editor editor;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( this );
    editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("STRING_1", "first String");
    editor.putInt("INT_1", arg1)
    editor.commit();
    //other stuff in onCreate
```

Other Activities

```
   SharedPreferences prefs;
   String mSTring = prefs.getString("STRING_1", arg1);
   Integer mInt =  prefs.getInt("INT_1", defValue)
```

Comment: Downvote. This is an oversimplification of what OP is asking. OP doesn't just want to store primitive data types for later retrieval, OP wants to share complex objects like a socket connection. Also, accessing SharedPreferences on the main thread (e.g. onCreate()) can be slow since it is going to do disk operations.

Comment: What I understood is that OP said he wanted to access IP and Port "VALUES" in other activities without using an intent, and AFAIK this is the best way. And for accessing the SharedPref on the main thread this was just an example for the OP to get the general idea. He can then put it in an AsyncTask or do whatever he wants.

Comment: @JonWillis Downvoting that solution is harsh. The values to be stored are just IP and port numbers which are primitive types. Reading/writing from shared preferences won't cause performance problems.

Comment: @Szymon Perhaps it is harsh. Poor code example aside, this answer ignores part of the question. <Also, what about the socket variable? How can I use it in Activity2b?> 



And reading and writing from shared preferences can certainly cause performance problems if it is done in excess or with large enough data sets. This is not a good answer.

Comment: @JonWillis True, it ignores the socket. I wouldn't pass the socket around anyway. Won't it be better to re-create it when it's needed and pass around/store the information that is needed for that?

Comment: @Szymon I discussed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing primitive data around in Intents is fine and is a common practice in Android. However, you should carefully read through [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) because it is fairly easy to lose a handle on your data because of the many states that are possible in an Android application.

As for your socket connection, you may want to use a `Service`, or perhaps an `IntentService`, see [Running in a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html). `IntentService` especially will set you up so that you aren't blocking the main (UI) thread with long-running network tasks.

So, instead of creating and accessing the socket connection in your Activities, you simply pass primitive data (e.g. IP and Port) to a `Service` with an `Intent` from your `Activity`. In that Service's onCreate, you would initialize the socket, and in its OnDestroy, you could close the connection.

This might seem like a little bit of overkill, but these patterns are the cornerstone of how responsive, maintainable, and stable Android apps are built.

Bonus points for flattening out your Activity classes by using [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Cheers.